# Set texture to Unity3D GUITexture from a spritesheet

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, hud

Is there any way to use a texture from a spritesheet for GUITextures? I'm just trying to avoid extra drawcalls caused by GUITextures.

Comment: If you worry about DrawCalls, Unitys current GUI will not satisfy you, even with workarounds like this.

Comment: I'm developing for mobile platforms. Currently I have one drawcall thanks to my spritesheet(which also includes my HUD buttons that I cannot use). And I don't know how many drawcalls will make trouble.

Comment: @user1919764 You'll want to use something like NGUI http://www.tasharen.com/?page_id=140 -- otherwise wait for Unity 4.6 to come out later this year. Right now, Unity's built-in GUI methods are not draw-call friendly. 1 GUITexture = 1 draw call, no matter the sprite.

Comment: Thanks. I think there is a proper way. If we add GUITexture to the scene without texture(it still keeps functionality) and add sprite to the scene with same poisition, we can keep draw calls same. Actually, I tried this method and it works. Only problem is if you change camera size at runtime, naturally, sprites position on the screen changes.